# Absolute timestamp as MP4 start time

Tags: video, ffmpeg, timestamp, html5-video, mp4

I'd like to store the exact start time a video was recorded on, inside its mp4 container.
I need a millisecond accuracy (i.e. year,month,day,hour,sec,milli).
Such an accuracy requires 8 bytes.

The only standard way I found to store a video creation time is to use the mvhd/tkhd/mdhd boxes creation_time field.
But according to the base media file format spec, the field only gives a granularity of seconds:

> creation_time is an integer that declares the creation time of this
>   track (in seconds since midnight, Jan. 1, 1904, in UTC time)

In version 0 the field size was 4 bytes, while in version 1 it was increased to 8 bytes. But the description remained unchanged so it can still only reflect a timestamp in up to second granularity. (for maintaining backward compatibility maybe?)

So finally, is there a standard way to store a single absolute timestamp with millisecond accuracy in a mp4 container?
If the only way to do it, is to store it as a custom metadata, is there an agreed common way to do it according to?

Comment: Have you looked at [XMP data](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/xmp/sdk/XMPspecification.pdf) which can be embedded in mp4s? You may be able to use the `xmpDM:startTimecode` in the Dynamic Media Schema (relative to creation date).

Comment: @K3N Thanks. That looks like the closest thing to a standard way of expressing an accurate start time.